# How to track referrer of referrer in web api

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, asp.net-web-api, referrer

I have this page A - `https://example.com/addproduct/`

Assume user has come to this page from page B `https://referrer.com/`.

An ajax request is being fired on this page to create product - `/api/products/ [POST]`.

I will get page A (`https://pagea.com/addproduct/`) as referrer in this products api but I want to get the referrer of this page A i.e. page B in api. What is the best way to achieve it?

Should I pass this from javascript in request body or http header? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

As long as page A and page B is under your site. When user navigate from page B to page A, you can put an identifier whenever user click navigation element on page B.

Example on page B, you have :

```
<button onclick="navigate()">Go to page A<button>
```

Then,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function navigate(){
     var currentLocation = window.location.href;
     window.location = "http://yoursite.com/?addproduct="+currentLocation;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Referrer could be of any domain, not necessary to be our site. Anyway I can read and add `document.referrer` in url on page load but Is it a good practice to keep referrer in url? Shouldn't we keep our url clean?

Comment: you're right, you can use document.referrer. If we following REST API best practice, you can keep your URL clean, just pass it (referrer value) on the POST body.